# How do I get IPython autoreload magic to load automatcially when using an embedded shell?

Tags: python, ipython

I have the following in my `ipython_config.py`:

```
print "Test autoreload" #confirm this gets loaded
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
```

And it seems to work for normal ipython sessions:

```
$ ipython
Test autoreload
In [1]: %autoreload 2
In [2]:
```

However, when using an embedded shell script that uses IPython.embed(), the autoreload magic no longer works.

For example, in `shell.py`:

```
from IPython import embed
embed()
```

This still loads my ipython_config.py, as evidenced by `"Test autoreload"` printing out, however the autoreload extension does not get loaded (no %autoreload magic):

```
$ python shell.py
Test autoreload
In [1]: %autoreload 2
ERROR: Line magic function `%autoreload` not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is a [(known)](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ipython.user/8083) bug. Extensions are only loaded if there is an Application, so when using embed, it won't get loaded (although the config is read).

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1144) on github to fix this, but it has never been implemented.

Comment: Interesting. I did find that Django had the [same issue](https://github.com/django/django/pull/512) at one point, and an IPython developer suggested using a "standard ipython startup" with TerminalIPythonApp instead of embed().

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
from IPython import embed
embed()
```

Use this

```
from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import TerminalIPythonApp
app = TerminalIPythonApp.instance()
app.initialize(argv=[])
app.start()
```

You can run `python shell.py`

```
In [1]: %autoreload 2

In [2]:
```